# Opencv - cvHoughLines2

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I am reading `Learning openCV` and I came across description of `cvHoughLines2` in this book. But I can't understand one thing.

I read about Hough transform and I think I understand it, so the parameters `rho` and `theta` are bit puzzling to me. When we have equation `rho=xcos(theta)+ycos(theta)` when we decide on some set of discrete values of `theta`, values of `rho` should be automatically known.

In this book it is said that `opencv` creates `rho`x`theta` accumlator array.

Does opencv just discretize angle as multiplies of `360/theta`? But how does the `rho` parameter fits? How are the values of `rho` discretized?

Comment: Hey, the link is  about [Hough Transform](http://folk.uib.no/eha070/mat262/lectures%202011/DIP3ELecture11_2011.pdf) , once you go through it, i am sure it will make you clear about the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, it seems you are confused. Have a look at [this page](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm). Given a set of points (the x's and y's) belonging to a line you can describe the same line by just two parameters r and theta. These are two independent parameters we want to find that best describe the line that we have the points on.

Comment: Yes, and to represent the accumlator array in computer memory we need to pick values for the angle (theta), and when we picked finite number of thetas we can calculate `r`. I don't understand why opencv wants me to pass him the values for both angle and a `r`. The angles alone should be enough to create accumlator array.

Comment: Ok, now I am sure you got the algorithm wrong, have a look at the page in my post and first put aside the way you think the algorithm works. the two params to opencv are the resolutions in these two dimensions. Or see the wikipedia page on Hough transform.

Answer (score 0):

in beginning you decide vector of theta lets say 10 numbers , you need to round the result to fall in pixel of matrix which row represent radius  and columns the angle
so if some line is in same angle and radius it will add the accumulator a value.
[0 36 .. 360]
also radius vector [1 2 3 .. 10]
then you create image M*N all zeros lets say for example only
[ 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0]
then you perform formula you write  at some radius and angleyour matrix become
[ 1 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0]

then
[ 1 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 0 0]
then
[ **2** 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0]
ans so on
then you can threshold and find only some lines or at some angles.